# gnome crashed on ubuntu while updating

Tags: gnome, updates

After I've installed openCV and after updating/upgrading `apt-get`, gnome crashed.

I was wondering how can I fix/reinstall/repair gnome.

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

If not, then I would try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: tried `sudo apt-get install iireinstall gnome-shell` didnt solve it , am trying now dist-upgrade